# My program to find the solution of a series is giving me wrong answers

Tags: c++, series

I was creating a program to find the solution to the series x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ... up to a certain term. The program is working but it is giving me wrong answers. Suppose if I take x = 5 and I wanted to find the sum up to 3 terms, it should give me 10.207(approx). But it is giving me an output of -15.8333. So please tell me where is the logical error in this program? I tried my best to find the error but I couldn't.

Here is the program:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    int N;
    unsigned long long int factorial(int x);
    long double evaluate(int x, int y = 1, int i = 1) {
        if (i >= N) return 0;
        if (i % 2) return pow(x, y)/factorial(y) - evaluate(x, y + 2, i + 1);
        return pow(x, y)/factorial(y) + evaluate(x, y + 2, i + 1);
    }
    int main() {
        int x;
        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Please enter the number of terms: ";
        cin >> N;
        long double result = evaluate(x);
        cout << "The evaluation result of the series is " << result << endl;
    }
    
    unsigned long long int factorial(int x) {
        if (x < 0) return -1;
        if (x == 0) return 1;
        return x * factorial(x - 1);

    }
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the program with a debugger to see where the code diverges from your algorithm?

Comment: **Don't** use `pow` to calculate integer powers, it uses floating point math so you can get an off by one error. It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unless using recursion is a requirement of the exercise, when an iterative solution is equally available, it should always be preferred. As you have found, following recursive logic can be difficult and can confuse whatever problem you are attempting to solve. An iterative approach here can be done is a simple `for` loop,

Answer (score 1):

I think the bugs are in the `evaluate` function:

```
long double evaluate(int x, int y = 1, int i = 1) {
  if (i > N) return 0;
  if (i % 2) return pow(x, y) / factorial(y) + evaluate(x, y + 2, i + 1);
  return -pow(x, y) / factorial(y) + evaluate(x, y + 2, i + 1);
}
```

Comment: I tested with x = 1 and N = 10, the output is 0.841471 which is indeed close to sin(1).
But apart from this, I hope this is just an exercise about understading how recursion works. Try rewriting this code without, it is simpler and much more efficient.